# How to get the ID of the current item inside a custom Combo Box and assign it to a Input Field

Tags: powerapp

I have added this custom Combo Box to a form inside my Power App form:-

[image]

[image]

and i am trying to always get the ID of the selected item inside Input field,, so inside the input  i defined this inside Update property:-

[image]

now this will work as long as i manually select an option inside the Combo Box, but when the form loaded and the default get set for the Combo box >> the value inside the Input field will be blank.. any idea how i can fix this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's probably blank because your `ThisItem.StoreID` is also blank.

[image]

Not really an answer but one way to find out:

1. Run again the form the start until the value inside the input field is blank, and don't click anything except the close (x) top-right corner.
2. Now, open your `DefaultSelectedItems` code focus on `ThisItem.StoreID`, put the cursor on the `StoreID` and you'll roughly know what's the value below Format text.

[image]

Tips: At any point of time you close (x) the form on the top-right corner, the variable values will be filled up upon writing the code. That will give you a rough idea of what to expect.